# How to handle null check when searching for a node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree, option-type

I have the following code to search for a node in a BST:

```
private Node<AnyType> searchAndGetNode(AnyType value) {
        Node<AnyType> currentNode = root; 
        while(currentNode != null && currentNode.getData() != null) {
            if (value.compareTo(currentNode.getData()) == 0) {
                return currentNode;
            } else if (value.compareTo(currentNode.getData()) < 0) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am aware of Optional.ofNullable() to get an Optional object and then use isPresent() to avoid null-check. But I could not think of any neat way to avoid null check comparison in the while loop in the above method. I am using Java 8. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `&& currentNode.getData() != null` part of the condition as it doesn't make sense for there to be null values in a binary tree (your cannot call `compareTo` on null, so where would you insert it into the tree?). Apart from that, there is nothing wrong with the null check you have.

However, for performance, you should not call `compareTo` twice for each value, but call it once and examine the result:

```
int cmp = value.compareTo(currentNode.getData());
if (cmp == 0) {
    return currentNode;
} else if (cmp < 0) {
    currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
} else { // cmp > 0
    currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I could not think of any neat way to avoid null check comparison
>   in the while loop

There's nothing wrong with `!=null`.

---

But you could use an interface with Leafs and Nodes instead (and make use of default method with Java 8).

```
interface Tree<T> {

    boolean isEmpty();

    default T getData() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    default Tree<T> getLeft() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    default Tree<T> getRight() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}

class Leaf<T> implements Tree<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }

}

class Node<T> implements Tree<T> {

    public Node(Tree<T> left, Tree<T> right, T data) {...}
    //implement getLeft, getRight etc.
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }   

}
```

Then there is no more need for null checks in your code (following @Boann on this point, where would you store a `null` reference in your BST?):

```
class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    ...

    private Tree<T> searchAndGetNode(T value) {
        Tree<T> currentNode = root; 
        while(!currentNode.isEmpty()) {
            int cmp = value.compareTo(currentNode.getData());
            if (cmp == 0) {
                return currentNode;
            } else if (cmp < 0) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
            }
        }
        return currentNode; //it will be a Leaf at this point
    }

}
```

Then you could just call `isEmpty()` to check whether a Node or a Leaf has been returned from the `searchAndGetNode` method.

Some might argue that `isEmpty()` could also be implemented in the `Tree` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check it somewhere, if not in the `while` condition than in the `getLeft()` and `getRight()` (either when you call it or inside it). The option you chose is better IMHO because you check only once while the other alternatives require multiple checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the null check. You must have some condition to determine when you finish searching the tree without finding the requested Node. Whether this check compares some reference to null or asks if some Optional is empty makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code works as it should. When you enter right/left child that does not exist or has null value, you will simply quit your while loop. You need an end condition to your loop, and null is the place.

I would only advise to replace

```
currentNode.getData() != null
```

with a method for this node, like `currentNode.hasData()`. This will hide your logic and will be more readable:)

```
     private Node<AnyType> searchAndGetNode(AnyType value) {
        Node<AnyType> currentNode = root; 
        while(currentNode != null && currentNode.getData() != null) {
            int comparedValue = value.compareTo(currentNode.getData());//compare once. Because this is a int
            if (comparedValue  == 0) {
                return currentNode;
            } else if (comparedValue  < 0) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeft();
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.getRight();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```